# c# System.OutOfMemoryException How can I solve it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, memory, out-of-memory

Hi I am using this function to calculate all the possible combinations of A List of Object "Ricerca" when I try to calculte the combination of more than 24 elemnts I get the System.OutOfMemory Exception. Is there a way I can solve this problem?

this is the function I use:

```
 private static List<List<Ricerca>> GetAllCombos(List<Ricerca> list)
    {
        int comboCount = (int)Math.Pow(2, list.Count) - 1;
        List<List<Ricerca>> result = new List<List<Ricerca>>();
        for (int i = 1; i < comboCount + 1; i++)
        {
            // make each combo here
            result.Add(new List<Ricerca>());
            for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
            {
                if ((i >> j) % 2 != 0)
                    result.Last().Add(list[j]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What contains the class "Ricerca"? Also, your code will repeat combinations, are you sure that's what you want? If you really want to do that you can simplify substantially the code, just clone the base list and remove from the clone the current index.

Comment: `2^24 = 16777216` - That's pretty big, you know? If you consider that each of those 16 mln of elements could contain up to 24 elements that's roughly 400M references in the heap. I do not believe your `OutOfMemoryException` is strange at all.

Comment: You are putting (x * 2**x)) items in to the list.  How big is List.Count?  With x = 24 that is 4026353184.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I know it's pretty big :-(

Comment: @jdweng the dimension of the List is not fixed  so it could be any

Comment: Gusman Hi how can I simplify the code? What I want is this: if have 3 elements {a,b,c} I want to get all the possible combination: a,b,c,ab,ac,bc... Could you please suggest me a better way to calculate all these combinations?

Answer (score 3):

Do you *really* need to hold them all in memory at once or would it be sufficient to get each combination one at a time so you can do something with it?

```
    private static IEnumerable<List<Ricerca>> GetAllCombos(IReadOnlyCollection<Ricerca> list)
    {
        var comboCount = (int)Math.Pow(2, list.Count) - 1;
        for (var i = 1; i < comboCount + 1; i++)
        {
            // make each combo here
            yield return list.Where((t, j) => (i >> j) % 2 != 0).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , in my code I have to loop all the combinations, but maybe you are right I don't need to hold them all in memory  at once. For every combination I have to calculate which is the waste and I have to keep only the ones with less waste but of course any elements of the initial List must be present.